# How to find URL requested by a C Binary

Tags: linux

I have a binary, which requests some external URL(It is hard-coded somewhere in code) for data. Since I don't have much idea about the code, I can't see the URL.

Is there a way, I can figure out the URL or IP, by running the program on Centos Linux.

Comment: Tcpdump should do it?

Comment: `strace` worked for me, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used following command to trace the connections in/out of my application.

```
strace -f -e trace=network -s 10000 ./a.out
```

Here,

> -f => Trace child processes as they are created by currently traced processes as a result of the fork(2) system call.
>
> -e trace=network => trace only network related things
>
> -s 10000 => the maximum string size to print (the default is 32).